# Google Docs thumbnail link returns 404

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

I have questions regarding the behavior of the Google Drive v3 API files resource `thumbnailLink` property for Google Docs files. There are two different types of thumbnail links created depending if the file is a Google Doc or other type of file. When going to the `thumbnailLink` URL for a Google Doc I always get a 404 response, **unless** I open it on a Chrome browser where I am logged in with the same Google account.

My questions about the thumbnail link are:

- What is the minimum OAuth scope required to access it?
- What are the exact criteria required for me to have see the thumbnail image in a browser instead of getting a 404?
- Is it possible to make the link to google doc thumbnails publicly accessible?

  - If not, is there some alternative way to build the thumbnail url?

I preferably want to avoid [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17392104/2212598) as it will either expose the access key or add complication by setting up a proxy.

This is the format of the google doc thumbnail link: `https://docs.google.com/feeds/vt?gd=true&id=1TjchRkZ0MxurnBkKNitDtoMQiyJUV6rv0z9HQ7kHEg0&v=3&s=AMedNnoAAAAAXaTCgqfi_sjlT4SAGAEd_ZABNBoSvMnM&sz=s220`

Other types of documents that use the following type of thumbnail link are publicly available: `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/JkrFnbTt-H1rJb-kXhjRsQI3NiiVu7DYD_L7kBLPvBzu4-ieXNB6Jb-ukQpHwujlzybaeirEyV0=s220`

I see this behavior in the Drive v3 "Try This API" screen with all scopes authorized. I go to the thumbnailLink immediately after getting the response so it is not expired.

Edit: The `webViewLink` works for me in the case of a google slide. So I am allowed to see the full contents publicly using that link but still get a 404 with the `thumbnaiLink`. Based on that inconsistency this seems like a bug, not  a security or permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. You are not supposed to be able to access the `thumbnailLink` if you don't have access to the file's content, as indicated [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files).

As a workaround, I would propose your app or whoever has access to the thumbnail links to upload the thumbnails to Drive, so that users can access these Drive links. Anyway, I don't know the details of your project so I'm not sure this would be a feasible or desired workaround.

Comment: Yes, I read the description of the property. That is an incredibly non-specific description. That is why I ask more specific questions. Also I would say I do have access to the file’s content if I can open the entire slide or document in the web browser.

Comment: Oh wait, can you access a document that is not public when you are not logged in your Google account?

Comment: Yes I can. Is access to content supposed to only load if you are logged into the google account on a browser?

Comment: That is interesting behavior, is that in the API documentation? I think access to the `webViewLink` is based on the OAuth 2.0 scope used to authorize the user. So if you use an access token which includes the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` then you should have access to see any files [based on this reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#drivev3).

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. Yes of course, with that scope you should be able to access the file.

Comment: I still can't load the thumbnail with that scope. That's why I'm confused about the behavior.

Comment: So how are you trying to access the URL? Can you provide a sample of the code you are working on?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the behavior in the ["Try this API" reference documentation filtering by google slides](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.presentation%27%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22files(name%2CmimeType%2CwebViewLink%2CthumbnailLink%2ChasThumbnail)%22%7D). All OAuth scopes are selected. I can load the URL from the `webViewLink` but I get a 404 from the `thumbnailLink`.

Comment: Hi @OMila please let me know if you need any more info/clarification or get any updates on this question. It will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I'm seeing this same behavior, have you found any workaround?

Comment: @David posted a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting a 404 is that the binary documents' thumbnails are publicly accessible. If you can get your hands to the `ThumbnailLink` field of Google File, you can download the thumbnail images using a simple `WebClient` without any authentication.

However, if you're trying to download a Google Document's thumbnail image using `WebClient` that will give you a 404 error, because Google expects that you download this `ThumbnailLink` URI using an authenticated connection.

I had faced a similar problem and was able to resolve it very easily. I use Google Drive API (version 3) for accessing the documents on Google Drive. The Google API has already authenticated my account which is how I am able to acquire the `ThumbnailLink` in the first place. But instead of using `WebClient`, use the DriveService's `HTTPClient` to download the thumbnail. The `HTTPClient` in DriveService creates an authenticated HTTP request allowing you to download thumbnails for Google Documents as well.

```
  private async Task<bool> DownloadThumbnail(string thumbnailURL, string localFile)
        {
            try
            {    
                var client = DriveService.HttpClient;
                var response = await client.GetAsync(thumbnailURL);
                using (var fs = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.CreateNew))
                    await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
                
                return true;    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // log error
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get thumbnail link with scopes `drive` and `drive.readonly`

It's private data Token or login required

`https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?authuser=0&sz=w280&id=[fileid]`

**sz** = size

**w** = width